# JQuery $(this) not recognized after HTML is modified

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a website consisting a few href links and 2 buttons that can change what those links are.

```
<div class="links">
     <p class="hlCategory">Classical Mechanics</p>
      <ul>
        <li><a class="topic_link" href="#">Position, Velocity, Acceleration</a></li>
        <li><a class="topic_link" href="#">Newton's Laws</a></li>
        <li><a class="topic_link" href=“#">Friction</a></li>
      </ul>
</div>

<div class="buttons">
      <p>Choose Dificulty:
        <button type=“button" onclick=“beginerButtonAction(this)">Beginer</button>
        <button type=“button" onclick="intermediateButtonAction(this)">Intermediate</button>
      </p>
 </div>
```

After the original html is loaded, when links are clicked, the alert function in the javascript file is triggered.

```
$(function(){
  $(".topic_link").click(function(){
    alert($(this).text());
  });
});
```

And everything works fine.

The problem arises after the buttons are pressed and the href are changed.

```
function beginerButtonAction(id) { 
    $( "div.links" ).remove();

    var newLinks;

       newLinks= '<div class="links">'+
         '<p class="hlCategory">Classical Mechanics</p>'+
              '<ul>'+
                '<li><a class="topic_link" href=“#”>Moment of Inertia</a></li>'+
              '</ul>'+
           '<p class="hlCategory"></p>'+
              '<ul>'+
                '<li><a class="topic_link" href=“#">Drag Force</a></li>'+
                  '</ul>'+
      '</div>';

    var $jNewLinks = $(newLinks);
    $("body").append($jNewLinks);
}

function intermediateButtonAction(id) { 
    $( "div.links" ).remove();

    var newLinks;

       newLinks= '<div class="links">'+
         '<p class="hlCategory">Classical Mechanics</p>'+
              '<ul>'+
                '<li><a class="topic_link" href=“#”>Torque</a></li>'+
              '</ul>'+
           '<p class="hlCategory"></p>'+
              '<ul>'+
                '<li><a class="topic_link" href=“#">Momentum</a></li>'+
                  '</ul>'+
      '</div>';

    var $jNewLinks = $(newLinks);
    $("body").append($jNewLinks);
}
```

After the html is modified the href no longer triggers the alert.  I want the alert to fire after html is changed.
Any thoughts?

Comment: Try `$("body").on("click",".topic_link",function() {...})`

Comment: Works great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach the event to a parent element which will always exist - in this case `<body>`.  You can delegate like this so new elements will bubble up and trigger the event:

```
$('body').on('click', ".topic_link", function(){
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

Read more about delegating events with `on()` here:

http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events

Comment: Works great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`$(selector).click` only adds events to the elements that are loaded & rendered when it is triggered. If you want to add `click` events to all the elements that match that selector you need the [`jquery.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method.

Here is an example:

```
$(document).on("click", ".class", function() {
   // do stuff
});
```

You can put in the place of the document any other selector. And jQuery will look within it and add events to all of the matching elements(`.class`) that it founds there.

Ex:

```
$("#myId").on("click", ".class", function() {
    // do stuff
}
```

This will add the `click` event to all of the elements that have the `.class` class even if they are added via a JS function.